# Microsoft Graph API - change notifications for CSP partner

Tags: notifications

We're CSP partner trying to implement change notifications for user resource.
Is there a chance to create a one subscription (on partner level) and be able to get notifications for our customers?
Other words, if we have 50 000 customers, does this mean that the only way to retrieve notifications for all of them is to create subscription for each of them (50 000 subscriptions in this case) ?

Regards ,

Pavle Kukric